# Clear without using float

Tags: html, css

Does it make any sense to use the `clear` property without using `float`?

For example:

```
<div>
    <img />
    <p></p>
</div>
```

The `img` tag has no `clear` property, while the `p` tag has `clear: both;`

Let's assume even the `div` has no `float` property.

Answer (score 2):

"The clear CSS property specifies whether an element can be next to floating elements that precede it or must be moved down (cleared) below them. The clear property applies to both floating and non-floating elements.

When applied to non-floating blocks, it moves the border edge of the element down until it is below the margin edge of all relevant floats. This movement (when it happens) causes margin collapsing not to occur."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear

Comment: I meant what if there is no float used in the page . then using clear is of no use right?

Comment: Clear is meant to be used around floats.